# Does $A$ have negative eigenvalues if the solution of $\dot{x}=Ax$ vanishes at infinity?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix with real entries. Consider the real
linear system of ordinary differential equations given in vector notations
as: $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=Ax(t)$ where $x(t)=\begin{pmatrix}u(t)\\
v(t)\end{pmatrix}$. If we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}u(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}v(t)=0$, how to prove that $A$ has negative eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3):

Not true.  Try $A = \pmatrix{0 & -2\cr 1 & -2\cr}$.  The eigenvalues are complex.

Comment: I have worked on the question.I only know that the given condition that x vanishes at infinity Implies that system is stable.And stable system must have negative eigen value.Pls can u clarify how the given conditions implies the stable system

Comment: @KisalayTripathi The *real part* of the complex eigenvalues is negative, so the oscillations decay to zero as $t\to\infty$.